# Autosys R11 Job Scheduling

Tags: autosys

I want to schedule a job using autosys R11. I use start_time to specify the job start time and also use start_mins to specify the interval.

But now, I want to schedule a job from 1:00 PM to 5:00 PM at regular interval (10 mins) so that the job will run at 1:00, 1:10,1:20,1:30,....,2:00,2:10,2:30 etc. How do I specify the end time (5:00 PM)?

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Veena

Answer (score 1):

Use a run_window: "13:00 - 17:00" and start_min: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50